# What is the correct flow type for window object?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I need to pass in window from the root of my application, and I'm confused as to what flow type I should be using.

I tried

```
export default class ListAttribute extends Component {
  props: {
   frameWindow: mixed
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.frameWindow.addEventListener('click', this.closeList, false) 
  }
  ....
}
```

This gives me `call of method addEventListener. Method cannot be called on mixed`, I tried refinement to no luck.

I tried looking here, but couldn't find anything for the bom itself. https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/#lib/bom.js

Answer (score 5):

[There currently isn't any typings for the `window` object](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2255) it seems. For now, it looks like the type of `any` is used.

Comment: The [Typescript definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L12835) linked from that ticket is over 14k lines of code! Which could explain why no one has bothered to do it for Flow...

Comment: I switched to Object, and disabled linting on that line :-(

frameWindow: Object // eslint-disable-line flowtype/no-weak-types

Comment: From that GitHub issue, it looks like they mentioned that "there was no good reason" that no one has typed it yet. I guess it just hasn't been a priority. If no one does it soon, I may give a try at it and send them a pull request with a week or two.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need any methods that are specific to `window`? If all you're doing is the one call to `addEventListener`, then that can be called on any `EventTarget`, which `window` certainly is. And since the default type for `window` is `any`, you should be able to pass it in for an `EventTarget`.

Here's a simpler example that hopefully shows that idea, without bringing in all the details of your code:

```
function withWindow(window: EventTarget) {
  window.addEventListener("click", (e: MouseEvent) => console.log(e), false); 
}

withWindow(window); // type checks fine!
```

Hope that helps!